# groovy interface method to properties

Tags: groovy

How can i get the methods of interface as a list of properties. I have the below interface with methods like this

```
interface ValuationEvent {
    String getType()
    String getAggregateId()
    String getXmlPayload()
}
```

I am trying to get a list of methods as properties some like final output should be

```
 [type, aggregateId, xmlPayload]
```

I tried using the properties method but it gives me a long list of 54 properties which do not contain the above properties

```
def documentProperties = ValuationEvent.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just get all methods, remove "get" from front and lowercase first letter?

```
ValuationEvent.getDeclaredMethods().collect{
    it.name.replace("get","").with{ it[0].toLowerCase() + it[1..-1] }
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `collect` the properties names:

```
interface ValuationEvent {
    String getType()
    String getAggregateId()
    String getXmlPayload()
}

def properties = ValuationEvent.metaClass.properties.collect { it.name }

assert properties == ['type', 'aggregateId', 'xmlPayload']
```